# Typo error with namespace in costum bundle symfony2

Tags: symfony, namespaces

I'm following the tutorial "Easy Way to Transform a Twitter OAuth Library into a Symfony 2 Bundle" [tuto](http://blog.solutionset.com/2012/09/14/easy-way-to-transform-a-twitter-oauth-library-into-a-symfony-2-bundle/)

But not working for me, Always I got this error:

*"The autoloader expected class "FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth" to be defined in     file "D:\xampp\htdocs\FEB/src\FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo."*

I've spent many days and I can´t find out what happen. I'm sure that is a namespace issue but i'm getting crazy.

My twitterapi.php

```
namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api;

use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth;

class TwitterApi {

    protected $apiKey;
    protected $apiKeySecret;
    protected $apiToken;
    protected $apiTokenSecret;

    public function __construct($apiKey, $apiKeySecret, $apiToken, $apiTokenSecret){
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->apiKeySecret = $apiKeySecret;
        $this->apiToken = $apiToken;
        $this->apiTokenSecret = $apiTokenSecret;
    }

    public function getapiKey(){
        return $this->apiKey;
    }

    public function getUsers($users, $url = 'users/lookup') {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->apiKey, $this->apiKeySecret, $this->apiToken, $this->apiTokenSecret);
        $users = $connection->get($url, array('screen_name' => $users));
        return $users;
    }

}
```

Any help, please?

Edit: 
My TwitterOAuth.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Abraham Williams (abraham@abrah.am) http://abrah.am
 *
 * The first PHP Library to support OAuth for Twitter's REST API.
 */

/* Load OAuth lib. You can find it at http://oauth.net */

namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta;

/**
 * Twitter OAuth class
 */
class TwitterOAuth {
  /* Contains the last HTTP status code returned. */
  public $http_code;
  /* Contains the last API call. */
  public $url;
  /* Set up the API root URL. */
  public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
  /* Set timeout default. */
  public $timeout = 30;
  /* Set connect timeout. */
  public $connecttimeout = 30; 
  /* Verify SSL Cert. */
  public $ssl_verifypeer = FALSE;
  /* Respons format. */
  public $format = 'json';
  /* Decode returned json data. */
  public $decode_json = TRUE;
  /* Contains the last HTTP headers returned. */
  public $http_info;
  /* Set the useragnet. */
  public $useragent = 'TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2';
  /* Immediately retry the API call if the response was not successful. */
  //public $retry = TRUE;




  /**
   * Set API URLS
   */
  function accessTokenURL()  { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'; }
  function authenticateURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'; }
  function authorizeURL()    { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'; }
  function requestTokenURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'; }

  /**
   * Debug helpers
   */
  function lastStatusCode() { return $this->http_status; }
  function lastAPICall() { return $this->last_api_call; }

  /**
   * construct TwitterOAuth object
   */
  function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token = NULL, $oauth_token_secret = NULL) {
    $this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    if (!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
      $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    } else {
      $this->token = NULL;
    }
  }


  /**
   * Get a request_token from Twitter
   *
   * @returns a key/value array containing oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
   */
  function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback; 
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * Get the authorize URL
   *
   * @returns a string
   */
  function getAuthorizeURL($token, $sign_in_with_twitter = TRUE) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
      $token = $token['oauth_token'];
    }
    if (empty($sign_in_with_twitter)) {
      return $this->authorizeURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}";
    } else {
       return $this->authenticateURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}";
    }
  }

  /**
   * Exchange request token and secret for an access token and
   * secret, to sign API calls.
   *
   * @returns array("oauth_token" => "the-access-token",
   *                "oauth_token_secret" => "the-access-secret",
   *                "user_id" => "9436992",
   *                "screen_name" => "abraham")
   */
  function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_verifier'] = $oauth_verifier;
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * One time exchange of username and password for access token and secret.
   *
   * @returns array("oauth_token" => "the-access-token",
   *                "oauth_token_secret" => "the-access-secret",
   *                "user_id" => "9436992",
   *                "screen_name" => "abraham",
   *                "x_auth_expires" => "0")
   */  
  function getXAuthToken($username, $password) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['x_auth_username'] = $username;
    $parameters['x_auth_password'] = $password;
    $parameters['x_auth_mode'] = 'client_auth';
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL(), 'POST', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * GET wrapper for oAuthRequest.
   */
  function get($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'GET', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * POST wrapper for oAuthRequest.
   */
  function post($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * DELETE wrapper for oAuthReqeust.
   */
  function delete($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'DELETE', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Format and sign an OAuth / API request
   */
  function oAuthRequest($url, $method, $parameters) {
    if (strrpos($url, 'https://') !== 0 && strrpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) {
      $url = "{$this->host}{$url}.{$this->format}";
    }
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->token, $method, $url, $parameters);
    $request->sign_request($this->sha1_method, $this->consumer, $this->token);
    switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
      return $this->http($request->to_url(), 'GET');
    default:
      return $this->http($request->get_normalized_http_url(), $method, $request->to_postdata());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Make an HTTP request
   *
   * @return API results
   */
  function http($url, $method, $postfields = NULL) {
    $this->http_info = array();
    $ci = curl_init();
    /* Curl settings */
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->ssl_verifypeer);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }
        break;
      case 'DELETE':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          $url = "{$url}?{$postfields}";
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ci);
    $this->http_code = curl_getinfo($ci, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $this->http_info = array_merge($this->http_info, curl_getinfo($ci));
    $this->url = $url;
    curl_close ($ci);
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Get the header info to store.
   */
  function getHeader($ch, $header) {
    $i = strpos($header, ':');
    if (!empty($i)) {
      $key = str_replace('-', '_', strtolower(substr($header, 0, $i)));
      $value = trim(substr($header, $i + 2));
      $this->http_header[$key] = $value;
    }
    return strlen($header);
  }
}
```

Edit2: [This is the folder structure](http://blog.solutionset.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Capture.png)

Comment: Read error message one more time :) Probably in your TwitterOAuth.php you have typo in namespace or class has wrong name.

Comment: Are you sure that in the `FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth.php` file is properly written `class TwitterOAuth { //... }`? Maybe you declared that class with another name.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, guys. I think all is correct. I've attached the class. Maybe 6 eyes see more than only two, ;)

Comment: It's weird, If I comment the namespace line //namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta; The same error is throw. This make me think that de namespace y wrong.

Comment: Remove the meta from the namespace

Comment: Is the error thrown with the code of `TwitterOAuth.php` as you've pasted it here? So is the `use` statement there commented out?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Pazi. 
If I remove "meta", not find the Class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\FEB\src\FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth.php line 51

Comment: Sorry @althaus, I dont understand you.

Comment: Change namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta; to namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api;

Comment: @Rpg600,  If I remove "meta", not find the Class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\FEB\src\FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth.php line 51

Comment: Guys, I've edit the post linking to an image of the folder structure

Comment: Its normal you need to add the proper use statement for this class and the others. Otherwise How can it find OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1, OAuthConsumer, OAuthUtil ... ?

Comment: @cmaciasg Sorry for being unclear: I wanted to point out, that the `namespace` statement has to be the first code in your file. You cannot put those `use` or `require` lines before it.

Comment: @althaus Yes, I know, :) Edit de code again, :)

Comment: @cmaciasg According to the tutorial the namespace has to be `namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api` and you have to add `use` statements for all the classes located in the `meta` subdir.

Comment: That is: In TwitterOAuth.php:
namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api;
use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;
.
.
.
use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthRequest;
???

Comment: See the answer I just posted summing up the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing all the comments up, your TwitterOAuth.php has to be like this:

```
<?php

/*
 * Abraham Williams (abraham@abrah.am) http://abrah.am
 *
 * The first PHP Library to support OAuth for Twitter's REST API.
 */

/* Load OAuth lib. You can find it at http://oauth.net */
//require_once('OAuth.php');

namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Api;

use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthConsumer;
use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthRequest;
use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;
use FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthUtil;

/**
 * Twitter OAuth class
 */
class TwitterOAuth {
  /* Contains the last HTTP status code returned. */
  public $http_code;
  /* Contains the last API call. */
  public $url;
  /* Set up the API root URL. */
  public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
  /* Set timeout default. */
  public $timeout = 30;
  /* Set connect timeout. */
  public $connecttimeout = 30; 
  /* Verify SSL Cert. */
  public $ssl_verifypeer = FALSE;
  /* Respons format. */
  public $format = 'json';
  /* Decode returned json data. */
  public $decode_json = TRUE;
  /* Contains the last HTTP headers returned. */
  public $http_info;
  /* Set the useragnet. */
  public $useragent = 'TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2';
  /* Immediately retry the API call if the response was not successful. */
  //public $retry = TRUE;




  /**
   * Set API URLS
   */
  function accessTokenURL()  { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'; }
  function authenticateURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'; }
  function authorizeURL()    { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'; }
  function requestTokenURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'; }

  /**
   * Debug helpers
   */
  function lastStatusCode() { return $this->http_status; }
  function lastAPICall() { return $this->last_api_call; }

  /**
   * construct TwitterOAuth object
   */
  function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token = NULL, $oauth_token_secret = NULL) {
    $this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    if (!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
      $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    } else {
      $this->token = NULL;
    }
  }


  /**
   * Get a request_token from Twitter
   *
   * @returns a key/value array containing oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
   */
  function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback; 
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * Get the authorize URL
   *
   * @returns a string
   */
  function getAuthorizeURL($token, $sign_in_with_twitter = TRUE) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
      $token = $token['oauth_token'];
    }
    if (empty($sign_in_with_twitter)) {
      return $this->authorizeURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}";
    } else {
       return $this->authenticateURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}";
    }
  }

  /**
   * Exchange request token and secret for an access token and
   * secret, to sign API calls.
   *
   * @returns array("oauth_token" => "the-access-token",
   *                "oauth_token_secret" => "the-access-secret",
   *                "user_id" => "9436992",
   *                "screen_name" => "abraham")
   */
  function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_verifier'] = $oauth_verifier;
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * One time exchange of username and password for access token and secret.
   *
   * @returns array("oauth_token" => "the-access-token",
   *                "oauth_token_secret" => "the-access-secret",
   *                "user_id" => "9436992",
   *                "screen_name" => "abraham",
   *                "x_auth_expires" => "0")
   */  
  function getXAuthToken($username, $password) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['x_auth_username'] = $username;
    $parameters['x_auth_password'] = $password;
    $parameters['x_auth_mode'] = 'client_auth';
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL(), 'POST', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }

  /**
   * GET wrapper for oAuthRequest.
   */
  function get($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'GET', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * POST wrapper for oAuthRequest.
   */
  function post($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * DELETE wrapper for oAuthReqeust.
   */
  function delete($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'DELETE', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Format and sign an OAuth / API request
   */
  function oAuthRequest($url, $method, $parameters) {
    if (strrpos($url, 'https://') !== 0 && strrpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) {
      $url = "{$this->host}{$url}.{$this->format}";
    }
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->token, $method, $url, $parameters);
    $request->sign_request($this->sha1_method, $this->consumer, $this->token);
    switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
      return $this->http($request->to_url(), 'GET');
    default:
      return $this->http($request->get_normalized_http_url(), $method, $request->to_postdata());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Make an HTTP request
   *
   * @return API results
   */
  function http($url, $method, $postfields = NULL) {
    $this->http_info = array();
    $ci = curl_init();
    /* Curl settings */
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->ssl_verifypeer);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }
        break;
      case 'DELETE':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          $url = "{$url}?{$postfields}";
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ci);
    $this->http_code = curl_getinfo($ci, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $this->http_info = array_merge($this->http_info, curl_getinfo($ci));
    $this->url = $url;
    curl_close ($ci);
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Get the header info to store.
   */
  function getHeader($ch, $header) {
    $i = strpos($header, ':');
    if (!empty($i)) {
      $key = str_replace('-', '_', strtolower(substr($header, 0, $i)));
      $value = trim(substr($header, $i + 2));
      $this->http_header[$key] = $value;
    }
    return strlen($header);
  }
}
```

Credit to @Pazi and @Rpg600 :)

Comment: I've tried it, but it Throws me this error: 

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\FEB\src\FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\TwitterOAuth.php line 54 
It's the hell!!!

Comment: Well, at least we have made ​​some progress from the first post.:)
Now the target is find the damned FEB\TwitterBundle\Api\Meta\OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1. :)

Comment: One question: The OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 class must have namespace as well?

Comment: It's used in the constructor and listed in the folder structure. Do you have an according file in the `meta` directory? I can only imagine that the underscores in the class name may cause issues with the autoloader.

Comment: I'm going to change the class name.

Comment: YEEEAHHHHHH, Remove the underscore and worked!!!! The first time that I see that kind of error.
Also I have to put the correct namespace in the meta folder classes.
Thank you very much, @altahus.